# Changing Logo for app within Facebook Developers Dashboard

Tags: ios, facebook

I would like to change my logo for my app in Facebook Developers. But it seems that their is no way to make the change live even if I have updated my app details with the appropriate items.

Any suggestions on how to go about making the change?

Comment: If you are app is approved for App Center you need to submit it again to change logo

Comment: @WizKid How can I resubmit the app? As it will not let me within app review